# Starting node on server with only open https connections

Tags: node.js

currently I have problem with starting node on a remote server which has very restricted connections. I know for sure that http is forbidden (outgoing).

Every time i start node i get this:

```
/tmp/node-v7.0.0-linux-x64/bin$ ./node 
net.js:10
const cares = process.binding('cares_wrap');                          ^

Error: EFILE
    at net.js:10:23
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:485:7)
    at NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:426:18)
    at tty.js:4:13
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:485:7)
    at Function.NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:426:18)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:141:48)
    at bootstrap_node.js:497:3
```

Anyone has an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Which part relate to your code? Can you post that part of your code?

Comment: Looks like you missing a package installed on the environment at first glance, have not worked with node/require in a while.

Comment: @DrakaSAN I didnt write any code. I cant even start node at all.

Comment: Starting just node should give you a prompt. Could you try to reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this error as well. In my case i'm running debian 8.

My /etc/resolv.conf was not readable by the user i was running node as, so i suggest you check things like the hosts file and name resolution, try to ping localhost as the user you want to run node as.

I ran this as root (This was to fix some other mistake of mine)

```
chmod +r /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then this as the user i wanted to run node as (In my case "peek" for the "synerty-peek" python platform)

```
ping localhost
```

Then node just worked again.

Comment: facing same issue in windows ENV. Any idea how to to same changes in windows?